# Cannot use CookieAuthenticaton and openidConnect Authentication in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have upgraded my project to asp.net core. But now my CookieAuthnetication and OpenIdConnectionAuthentication methods are not working. They have become obsolete.

**Startup.cs Configure method**

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
                SignInScheme = "Cookies",
                Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ClientId = "integapay.client",
                ClientSecret = "mySecret",
                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = { "openid", "profile", "api.public", "offline_access" },
                GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
                SaveTokens = true
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

They moved it into the Conifguration Service Part

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();      
        services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options => SetOpenIdConnectOptions(options));
    }
    private void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
    {           
        options.Authority = Configuration["auth:oidc:authority"];
        options.ClientId = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientid"];
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.ClientSecret = Configuration["auth:oidc:clientSecret"];
        options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("api_back");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    }
```

In the Configure call you only have to call

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Hope this helps. :)